# get the value from launchOptions at application(.... launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I am trying to get the value for launchOptions from UIApplicationDelegate

`func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {`

If the launchOptions is a NSDictionary I probably can retrieve value by

`launchOptions[launchOptions.UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]`

But the object is `[NSObject: AnyObject]`. How to retrieve value for this type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variant is not safe, better use `if let` statement:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if let options = launchOptions as? [String: AnyObject],
           notifyPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] {
            // do smth with notifyPayload
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift is full of try and adjust

Here is my own answer.

```
  let notifPayload = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey as String!] as? NSDictionary
```